# use shell script to traverse subdirectories and do grep

Tags: shell, grep

My directory has the following structure (on Mac)

```
main_folder/
 |_folder1/
 |_folder2/
 |_folder3/
```

each sub folder has a file that has the identical name "classFile.trans"
I want to traverse the sub folders and do grep on the file classFile.trans. But I don't know how to save the output new file in the corresponding sub folder. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
find file in ./main_folder/**classFile.trans; do

grep -v "keyword" $file > newClassFile.trans     #how do I save the output new file in the corresponding sub folder?

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to run the grep in each subdirectory:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in ./main_folder/*; do
 ( cd $d; 
   file=classFile.trans
   test -f $file && grep -v "keyword" $file > newClassFile.trans
 ) 
done
```

The parentheses cause the body of the loop to iterate in a new subshell, so the working directory of the main shell is not changed.  However, this makes error messages from `grep` fairly useless.  If any of the classFile.trans is not readable, for example, the error message will not indicate which directory.  So it is probably better to do:

```
for d in ./main_folder/*; do grep -v keyword $d/$file > $d/$newfile; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `find ./main_folder/ -name "classFile.trans" `; do 
   newFile=`dirname $file`/newClassFile.trans; 
   grep -v "keyword" $file > $newFile
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command has `-exec*` flags that allow it to run commands for each file matched. For your case you would do:

```
find ./main_folder -name classFile.trans \
     -execdir $SHELL -c "grep -v '$keyword' {} >newClassFile.trans" \;
```

(`\` and linebreak added so the whole command can be read without scrolling)

Breaking the various arguments down:

- `-name classFile.trans` searches for all files named `classFile.trans`
- `-execdir` runs everything up to the `;` character *in the directory that contains the matched file*
- `$SHELL -c` runs your $SHELL (e.g., /bin/bash) with the `-c` argument which immediately executes its respective value instead of creating an interactive shell that you can type in

  - `"grep -v '$keyword' {} >newClassFile.trans"` runs your grep and output redirection in the file's respective directory thanks to `-execdir`; note that find turns `{}` in to the matched file's name
  - This is necessary so the `>` redirection runs in the sub-command, not the "current" shell the find command is being run in
- `\;` escapes the `;` character so it can be sent to find instead of acting as a command terminator

A test:

```
# Set up the folders and test files
$ mkdir -p main_folder/{f1,f2,f3}
$ for i in main_folder/f?; do printf 'a\nb\nc\n' >$i/classFile.trans; done

# Contents of one of the test files
$ cat main_folder/f1/classFile.trans
a
b
c

# Set the keyword to the letter 'b'
$ keyword=b

$ find ./main_folder -name classFile.trans -execdir $SHELL -c "grep -v '$keyword' {} >newClassFile.trans" \;

# newClassFile.trans was created sans 'b'
$ cat main_folder/f1/newClassFile.trans
a
c
```